# Python BeautifulSoup - Looping through multiple pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to first grab all the links from a page, when get the URL for the "next" button and keep looping until there are no more pages. Been trying to get a nested loop going to achieve that but for some reason BeautifulSoup does never parse the second page.. only the first one and then stops..

Hard to explain but here is the code should be easier to understand what i am trying to explain :)

```
#this site holds the first page that it should start looping on.. from this page i want to reach page 2, 3, etc.
   webpage = urlopen('www.first-page-with-urls-and-next-button.com').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

for tag in soup.findAll('a', { "class" : "next" }):

    print tag['href']
    print "\n--------------------\n"


#next button is relative url so append it to main-url.com
    soup = BeautifulSoup('http://www.main-url.com/'+ re.sub(r'\s', '', tag['href']))

#for some reason this variable only holds the tag['href']
    print soup

    for taggen in soup.findAll('a', { "class" : "homepage target-blank" }):
        print tag['href']

        # Read page found
        sidan = urlopen(taggen['href']).read()

# get title
        Titeln = re.findall(patFinderTitle, sidan)

        print Titeln
```

Any ideas? So sorry for poor english, i hope i will not get hammered :) Please ask if i have explained it to poorly i will do my best to explain some more. Oh and i am new to Python - as of today (as you might have figured:)

Comment: Why do you call `urlopen` the first time, but pass BeatifulSoup() the URL directly the second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `urlopen` on the new url and pass the resulting file object to BeatifulSoup I think you'll be all set.  That is:

```
wepage = urlopen(http://www.main-url.com/'+ re.sub(r'\s', '', tag['href']))
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
```

Comment: Thanks! Nows its trying to load a page, now i get some unicodeerror cause of non-english characters hmm:

Comment: UnicodeError: URL u'http://www.main-url.com//bilf%C3%B6rs%C3%A4ljning/f\xf6retag/3' contains non-ASCII characters

Comment: I'm glad it helped out!  If you have a moment, please check the checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as an accepted answer. You probably want to open a new question about the Unicode errors, and you'll want to include the actual URL in the question so that we can see the data ourselves.  Also, make sure you show the complete traceback from Python and the corresponding lines of code.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For the line:

`soup = BeautifulSoup('http://www.main-url.com/'+ re.sub(r'\s', '', tag['href']))`

try:

`webpage = urlopen('http://www.main-url.com/'+re.sub(r'\s','',tag['href'])).read()`

`soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)`

Comment: @larsks - yes, I know, we clicked the answer button within a minute of each other so I hadn't seen your answer